# Changing hard drive

Tags: 14.04, backup, usb-drive

I have a laptop which has a broken hard drive. I am going to copy every piece of data from it (including the windows 7 which is in it) to an external hard drive. To do this I'll be using a flash drive with Ubuntu 14.04 in it.

Problem is that I do not know how to do this. I know how to make the USB Ubuntu but I'm not sure if it needs an extra program in it to copy everything from the old hard drive and put it in a new one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/285455/how-to-migrate-ubuntu-windows-7-dualboot-from-hdd-to-hddssd-without-reinstall Although it says SSD it you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Form Live ubuntu session:

Old drive: /dev/sda

New drive: /dev/sdb (no partitions on the drive AT ALL)

Execute: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

This will copy EVERYTHING from old drive to new drive.